# Alternative of PIL/Pillow for using ImageField in Django Models

Tags: python, django, pip, shared-hosting

I am setting a django project on Shared hosting server using `virtualenv` where I don't have `root access`. Also `sudo` doesn't works.I am using `ImageField` in models that require `PIL/Pillow` to be installed.But when I try

`pip install pillow`

I get this error:

```
unable to execute gcc: Permission denied
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

So is there any alternative available for `PIL/Pillow` which can be installed without `root access and gcc permissions`? (No permissions even in the virtualenv)

Comment: Change your provider to one that is sensible. You can use heroku which supports Python and gcc and virtualenv and Pillow/PIL plus is available for free; instead of trying to work around this problem. Or Google App Engine, OpenStack, etc.

Comment: Yep thinking of that...if things not work out will move the application to cloud...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageField requires the Pillow library, see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/, no two ways around that. You will need to install it. There are several solutions in your case:

1. Install/get permission to run gcc on the server
2. Compile somewhere else, where the setup is identical and copy the files
3. Change your code to not use ImageField